# If $\lambda^n $ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ then $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to figure out whether the following statement is correct:

> If $\lambda^n $ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ associated to a certain
>   eigenvector $v$ then $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ associated to
>   the same eigenvector $v$.

I know that the opposite statement is correct, that is, if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$ associated to a certain eigenvector $v$ then $\lambda^n $ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$ associated to the same eigenvector $v$.

I tried to guess some matrices to find out a counter example but I couldn't find anything. It seems that if we take $A$ to be diagonal matrix then the statement is always correct. In particular if we take $A$ such that $A^n$=$\lambda^n I $ then it must be that $A=\lambda I$.

Comment: If $4$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$, is $2$ or $-2$ the eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: Consider $A=-I$, $\lambda=1$, $n=2$.

Comment: there are several $\lambda$'s that can do the job.

Comment: It means that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\mu$ with $\mu^n= \lambda^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In particular, if we take $A$ such that $A^n = \lambda^n I$, then it must be that $A = \lambda I$.

This is not the case.  Two examples:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}
$$
Note that $v = (1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A^2 = I$, but not of $A$.
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
Note that $v = (0,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A^2 = 0$, but not of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for very much for noting this.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those problems that can be solved with a little matrix algebra. Let's work with complex matrices for simplicity (because then we can take $n$-th roots without worrying whether or not they exist). Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Then

$$\det(A^2-\lambda I)=0$$

Because $A$ and $\sqrt \lambda I$ commute, we have the identity:

$$A^2-\lambda I = (A-\sqrt\lambda I)(A+\sqrt\lambda I)$$

Therefore

$$\det(A^2-\lambda I)=\det(A-\sqrt\lambda I)\det(A+\sqrt\lambda I)=0$$

So at least one of $\sqrt\lambda$ and $-\sqrt\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. You can easily find an example to show that both need not be eigenvalues by letting $A$ be a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\sqrt\lambda$ and, say, $6$.

A generalization of this argument shows that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$, then at least one of the $n$-th roots of $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but not necessarily all of them.